# KeyError: "The name 'boosted_trees/QuantileAccumulator/' refers to an Operation not in the graph." when loading saved model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I created a TensorFlow estimator:

```
outlier_estimator = tf.estimator.BoostedTreesClassifier(
    n_batches_per_layer = 15,
    feature_columns=outlier_feature_columns, 
    model_dir="./tensorboard_logs/wifi_outliers/", 
    n_classes=2
)
```

and saved it:

```
def serving_input_receiver_fn():
    inputs = {
        "signal_0": tf.placeholder(shape=[1], dtype=tf.float32, name="signal_0"),
        "signal_1": tf.placeholder(shape=[1], dtype=tf.float32, name="signal_1")
    }
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(inputs, inputs)

outlier_estimator.export_savedmodel(export_dir_base="./export/", serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn)
```

But when I try to load saved model

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(
        sess,
        [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
        "./export/1551699998"
    )
```

**I faced an error:**

> KeyError: "The name 'boosted_trees/QuantileAccumulator/' refers to an
>   Operation not in the graph."

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using:
Python 3.7
tensorflow 1.13.1

Comment: Hi man, I got exactly the same problem, any clues?

Comment: @benjamin Hi! No any solution to this problem, sorry.

Comment: just one observation, if you change the model from BoostedTree to a naive linear model, it has no problem exporting at all. So the issue might be caused by how the boosted tree model is modeled in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Updating my Tensorflow version to Tensorflow 2 (precisely tf 2.1.0) solved the problem